# Loop through table and extract certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with project details and their expiration dates. If the project is expired, it outputs it to another sheet.

I'm trying to make a Refresh button on the Expired project sheet that would loop through that table and extract all of the expired projects.

```
Sub refresh_expired()
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet: Set wsMaster = Worksheets("MASTER")
    Dim wsList As Worksheet: Set wsList = Worksheets("LIST")

    Dim tblList As ListObject: Set tblList = wsList.ListObjects("digsafe_list")
    Dim tblExp As ListObject: Set tblExp = wsMaster.ListObjects("expired_list")
    Dim tblList_row As ListRow
    Dim tblExp_row As ListRow

    Dim not_empty As String
    Dim temp_digsafe As String, temp_work As String
    Dim temp_date As Date
    Dim tRows As Long, tCols As Long

    If tblList.DataBodyRange.Rows.count <> 0 Then
        Set tblExp_row = tblExp.ListRows.Add
        Set tblList_row = tblList.ListRows.Add

        For i = 1 To tblList.DataBodyRange.Rows.count
            If tblList_row.Range(7, i).Value < 1 Then
                temp_digsafe = tblList_row.Range(1, 1).Value
                tblExp_row.Range(1, i).Value = temp_digsafe

                temp_date = tblList_row.Range(7, i).Value
                tblExp_row.Range(1, 4).Value = temp_date
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
   End If
End Sub
```

[image]